# What gift do girls prefer in Belarus?

Tags: europe, gifts, belarus, romance

Soon I will visit my friend in Belarus.
And to be honest I have no idea what to give her on a first date. What gifts do girls in Belarus like? Is there anything I shouldn't give to her?

Comment: What would you give a girl on a first date where you come from? When you answer that, you'll have the answer to your question.  Because of that, I am close voting this question as 'opinion-based'.

Comment: Homer Simpson show us that the best gift a girl can expect is a bowling ball: http://www.simpsoncrazy.com/content/screenshots/episodes/7g11/7g11_007.jpg

Comment: Preferences are inherently subjective, thus this question is unanswerable objectively. Please have a read on the Help Centre to get a better idea of the [questions that are on topic on Travel SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: In any country girls like flowers, the best variant. If you don't know other her preferences. You can use  service flower delivery in Belarus http://by-flowers.com/. There are many good reviews I know)

Comment: [Food](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsa3XWw5hFE).